# Admin redirected to /home after back button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this admin middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if ($request->user()->is_admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

And in the logincontroller, if the user is admin, they are redirected to `/admin.` and if not redirected to `/home.`

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Now, when admin logs in, they are redirected to `/admin` but, on clicking back button of browser they are in `/home`. How could i not redirect the admins to `/home`. `/home` is under auth middleware group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because that user is now authenticated.

Laravel comes with a Middleware called `RedirectIfAuthenticated` which will check if the user is authentitcated and if so redirect them somewhere else.

You would need to edit that middleware to be something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return $request->user($guard)->is_admin
            ? redirect('/admin')
            : redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are `authenticated`. When you press back button it means from `/admin` you want to go back to `/login` but before calling view it is checked where the user is logged in or not. Since you haven't logged out and are logged in, you will be redirected to default path `/home`
..

In `Auth` folder there is a `LoginController` where you can see this line

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

If you want to add logic you can change it here. This is the default path.